# Please I'm using fetch to get data from an API, but only the JSX return without the products. Api is from: http://fakestoreapi.com/docs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux

Please my code just returns the JSX without the contents from the API.
I tried using the fetch() when I console.log, I see the array of products. My problem is how to output these products from the API.

Please help me debug, I've tried different approaches but I've always been stocked at this point. Thank you.

Product.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { title, image, price, category } = products;

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const getProducts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
    const data = await res.json();

    setProducts(data);
    setLoading(false);

    console.log(data);
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <h4>Loading.....</h4>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {!loading && products.length === 0 ? (
        <p className='center'>No logs to show....</p>
      ) : (
        products.map((product) => (
          <div class='card' style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={products.id}>
            <img src={image} class='card-img-top' alt='...' />
            <div class='card-body'>
              <h5 class='card-title'>Card title</h5>
              <p class='card-text'>
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
            <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
              <li class='list-group-item'>{title}</li>
              <li class='list-group-item'>$ {price}</li>
              <li class='list-group-item'>{category}</li>
            </ul>
            <div class='card-body'>
              <a href='#' class='card-link'>
                Card link
              </a>
              <a href='#' class='card-link'>
                Another link
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Comment: Just a tip in future, open the developer console and hit the "console" tab. If you put the code back the way you had it, you should see an error pointing to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know too. But this worked for me.

```
products.map(({ title, image, price, category }, index) => (
      <div key={index} class='card' style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={products.id}>
        <img src={image} class='card-img-top' alt='...' />
        <div class='card-body'>
          <h5 class='card-title'>Card title</h5>
          <p class='card-text'>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
            the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
        </div>
        <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
          <li class='list-group-item'>{title}</li>
          <li class='list-group-item'>$ {price}</li>
          <li class='list-group-item'>{category}</li>
        </ul>
        <div class='card-body'>
          <a href='#' class='card-link'>
            Card link
          </a>
          <a href='#' class='card-link'>
            Another link
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  )}
```

You need to add `{ title, image, price, category }` in the map function. I think it is because the map function doesn't know what is `{ title, image, price, category }` variables and you need to add a key every time you use the map function and don't forget to change `class=` to `className`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I don't understand the function of the (index)

Comment: since i destructured the { title, image, price, category }= Products. i thought the map should read the details from it .

Answer (score 1):

You have to first destructure the properties that you are trying to use in you JSX (title, price, category), then you can show them.

```
   products.map((product) => {
          const { title, price, category } = product;
          return (****your JSX goes here***)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use  `product?.title ,product?.price,product?.category`  to access individual fields.
This approach is better than the other as you will not get an error for the field that is not in the API.